# Does Laravel validator check the MIME type of the file or the extension?

Tags: php, laravel

My application requires a user to upload a Spreadsheet. This spreadsheet data is then converted to the database. I am building a Middleware to prevent any user error or security incursion. After looking at the Laravel documentation, I found that the Validator in Laravel checks MIME types.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->validate([
        'spreadsheet' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls'
    ]);
    
    return $next($request);
}
```

Does this check the MIME type or the file extension? As for an xlsx or xls file, the MIME type is:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Which should I be checking?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  [
  'file'      => $request->file,
  'extension' => strtolower($request->file->getClientOriginalExtension()),
  ],
  [
  'file'          => 'required',
  'extension'      => 'required|in:doc,csv,xlsx,xls,docx,ppt,odt,ods,odp',
  ]
);
```

Comment: But is this checking the extension or the MIME type? Nothing stops someone from naming it `.xlsx.php` etc... To be sure, the file MIME type should be checked and I feel as if this is checking the extension

Comment: yes i think it is checking MIME type.
about the problem you are mentioning i dont know honestly but if you figure it out write here too please